# Automatically connect to internet

Tags: networking, usb-modem, 3g, automatic

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my laptop, I am using 3G USB modem to connect to the internet (sometimes I do not have direct access to this laptop, but I need it to stay online). But every day or two it keeps disconnecting from this network. I was wondering, is there any way to set the system to connect automatically at specific time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nmcli` and `cron` to bringing up connection at specific time.

First you create connection using Network-Manager.

Then start terminal to test some things

- list all NM connections: `nmcli con`
- start connection: `nmcli con up id ConnectionName`
- down connection: `nmcli con down id ConnectionName`

If work, setup `cron` to trigger connection

`sudo crontab -e`

at the end add

```
45 10 * * * nmcli con up id bdc
```

this will trigger command every day at 10 h and 45 min.
In `cron` you can specify min, hour, day, month ...
Also you can start connectio every min

```
* * * * * nmcli con up id bdc
```

More example how to setup time in cron can find [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)